# How do i increase an element value from column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have this Pandas code (look below) but turn out it give me this error: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

_data0 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\DataScience task\\Gender_Age.xlsx")

_data0['Age' + 1]
```

I wanted to change the element values from column 'Age', imagine if I wanted to increase the column elements from 'Age' by 1, how do i do that? (With Number of Children as well)

The output I wanted:

```
    First Name  Last Name      Age      Number of Children
0   Kimberly    Watson          36                 2
1   Victor      Wilson          35                 6
2   Adrian      Elliott         35                 2
3   Richard     Bailey          36                 5
4   Blake       Roberts         35                 6
```

Original output:

```
    First Name  Last Name      Age      Number of Children
0   Kimberly    Watson          24                 1
1   Victor      Wilson          23                 5
2   Adrian      Elliott         23                 1
3   Richard     Bailey          24                 4
4   Blake       Roberts         23                 5
```

Comment: There's a different 12 in age in the two outputs you show, yet you talk about a difference of 1. Can you explain more clearly what you mean and where these come from?

Comment: Pardon for the mistakes in my question, I meant to ask: How do I increase the value of  
Age by 12 and Number Of Children by 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'] - 12
df['Number of Children'] = df['Number of Children'] - 1
```